# Element manifest must be declared

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 3.6, I'm trying to create a new android app but it shows that Elment manifest must be declared [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue5oG.png)
I've checked and I'm not find any solutions. Can anyone help me!!

Comment: yea I'm seeing the same. it's an irritating Android Studio bug, it can't identify the android tags though compilation on command line is going fine. stupid irritating bug!

Comment: I simply solved it,  I tried to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio

Comment: I'm seeing the error in 3.6.2 but not in 4.1 canary build. hope it keeps working, thanks